# How to align a list of objects according to their string properties?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, list

I have a class for holding data as follows:

```
public class MyData
{
   string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I have `List<List<MyData>>()` as the result set. Now I want to align these lists according to their `Name` property and use `null` value as a padding. For example:

`{{"A", "B", "C"}, {"B","D"}}` will be

```
{
   {"A", "B", "C"}, 
   {null, "B","D"}
}
```

There are similar questions for aligning list of numbers but not sure how to apply them in this situation. Any ideas how I can approach this ?

**EDIT:**

I need to shift right when aligning; no nulls in between.

However lists dont have to be same length

Comment: Made any progress on this?

Comment: Can you give more examples? Why isn't the first one `{"A", "B", "C", null}` and the second  `{null, "B", null, "D"}`?

Comment: Not really @PatrickHofman I dont know I cant think of anything else but a gory algorithm with lots of for-loops. Looking for some ideas to start

Comment: Or do you just add `null`(s) at the start of the list to make up for the length?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes exactly I need to shift right to match the lengths no nulls in between

Comment: Array seems more useful than a list for this case.

Comment: When you say "However lists dont have to be same length", you mean the input lists or the output lists?

Comment: Does value of `MyData` matters? What should we do in this case: `{"A", "B"}, {"B", "C"}`?

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the maximum length of a list:

```
var max_size = list.Max(x => x.Count);
```

And then add the appropriate number of nulls before each inner list. `max_size` will be used to calculate such number:

```
var result = list
    .Select(x =>
        Enumerable.Range(0, max_size - x.Count)
            .Select(y => new MyData()) //Should this be (MyData)null?
            .Concat(x)
            .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Please note that I am assuming that `new MyData()` will give you an object whose `name` property is `null`.

Please note that this will not modify the original list, but instead create a new one with the right alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method that buckets an enumeration of an enumeration by a property.

```
public static T[][] Bucket<T, TOrig>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TOrig>> self, Func<TOrig, T> selector)
{
    List<T> allValues = self.SelectMany(t => t).Select(selector).Distinct().ToList();
    List<T[]> ret = new List<T[]>();
    foreach (ICollection<TOrig> col in self)
    {
        T[] append = new T[allValues.Count];
        foreach (TOrig orig in col)
        {
            T val = selector(orig);
            append[allValues.IndexOf(val)] = val;
        }
    }
    return ret.ToArray();
}
```

Note: the output is an array of arrays, because that makes a lot more sense for bucketing than `List<T>`. Feel free to call `ToList()` if you *really* need Lists.

For you:

```
List<List<MyData>> yourListOfLists;
string[][] bucketed = yourListOfLists.Bucket(m => m.Name);
```